# SQL "CREATE TABLE" Query not working in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm getting an error on the following query that I can't find how to fix, here's the query code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `minecraftitems.blocks` (`player` varchar(16) NOT NULL, `itemid` text NOT NULL, `action` text NOT NULL,`time` big(20) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The error code:

```
10:48:05 [GRAVE] com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blocks` (`player` varchar(16) NOT NULL, `itemid` tex' at line 1
```

EDIT:
Changed the query to:

```
            PreparedStatement sql = con.prepareStatement(
                  "SELECT '" + db + "'; CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `minecraftitems.blocks` (\r\n" + 
                        "    `player` varchar(16) NOT NULL,\r\n" + 
                        "    `itemid` text NOT NULL,\r\n" + 
                        "    `action` text NOT NULL,\r\n" + 
                        "    `time` bigint(20) NOT NULL\r\n" + 
                        "    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;");
```

and i'm getting this error now:

```
11:07:22 [GRAVE] com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `minecraftitems.blocks` (`player` varchar(16) N' at line 1
```

PhpMyAdmin runs the query without any problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a "find my typo question"

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error in your query. Its `bigint` not just `big` change it to `time bigint(20) NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `minecraftitems.blocks` (
    `player` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    `itemid` text NOT NULL,
    `action` text NOT NULL,
    `time` big(20) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The problem is that `big` is not a data type.  Do you mean `bigint` or `time` or `timestamp` or something else?  Storing a field named `time` as an integer seems suspicious.

Note:  This creates a table called "mincraftitems.blocks", which seems the intent of the statement.  If you are trying to create `blocks` in `minecraftitems`, then you would want:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `minecraftitems`.`blocks` (
```

Comment: Shouldn't that also be `\`minecraftitems\`.\`blocks\``? (backticks around the database and table name each)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Perhaps for some perverse reason the OP wants a period in the name of the table.  I added a note to this effect.

Comment: it's for a timestamp & I want to create a table in a database named  blocks.

Comment: @davidp027: if the _database_ is named `blocks` then you have the name the wrong way round. It must be `\`blocks\`.\`minecraftitems\``. First you specify the database, then the table name. Please see the manual for details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

Comment: I already selected the database "minecraftitems" & my query works fine when I do it in phpmyadmin. Seems to be my formatting with java

Answer (score 0):

Made in in one line, and removed the SELECT db; and it worked. Here's my query

```
PreparedStatement sql = con.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + db + ".blocks (`player` varchar(16) NOT NULL, `itemid` text NOT NULL, `location` text NOT NULL, `action` text NOT NULL, `time` bigint(20) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1");
```